# VMware Server 2 on Windows 2008 Server Core

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, vmware-server

I have an older server (retired database box in fact) that doesn't fit the requirements for VMware ESX/ESXi or Microsoft's Hyper-V but runs VMware Server 2 just fine. The host OS is currently Windows 2003 Standard. While it does the job just fine, I could hope for something a bit more "svelte" out of the box. Thus Windows 2008 Server Core caught my eye.

Granted, I've never actually built a server core box, but it sounds like it might make a great host for VMware Server. I've yet to find an instance of anyone who's done it though. So, before I pervert a workstation for testing I figured I'd ask here:

Anyone tried VMware Server on 2008 server core? Anything to be aware of or gotchas?

*(yes, I could also go with Linux for a thinner host, but this seems like a great excuse to bring up a 2008 server core box!)*

Edit: I guess I should mention this server hosts our development environments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't work. This is answered on [VMware's FAQ for VMware Server 2:](http://www.vmware.com/products/server/faqs.html)

> Can I install VMware Server 2 on a
> Core installation of Windows Server
> 2008 host operating system?
>
> **No**, VMware
> Server 2 can only be installed on a
> Full installation of Windows Server
> 2008 host operating system.  However,
> both Core and Full installations of
> Windows Server 2008 are supported as
> guest operating systems.

Comment: Ah thanks. You'd think with an hour of web searches I could've found that! Clearly, my google-fu is weak.

And hell, I might just try it anyways...

Comment: Please report your findings here afterwards. =]

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed.

The VMware Server installer stops the install with "Windows 2008 Server Core installations are not supported" And so it ends. Guess I'll go with a stripped down CentOS for a "lean" host

Comment: Are you sure your box isn't up to ESX standards?

Comment: no :-)  Based on the white box list (http://www.vm-help.com/esx/esx3.5/Whiteboxes_SATA_Controllers_for_ESX_3.5_3i.htm) it just might work. I'm just hesitant to commit without knowing for certain.

Answer (score 0):

Installed Virtual Server version 2.0.1 build 156745 on a Windows Server 2008 core with SP2 and the installation completed succesfully.
Hovwer, while doing tasks in the webinterface I encountered many errors (popup: The server response included one or more errors) and tasks were never completed.

Then I read about the fact that Vmware server is not supported on a Core installation.